# The meaning of "XX GAME お客様サポート係 横井でございます"

Tags: meaning, kanji

Recently I sent an email to a game's support channel and the first paragraph of their reply email contains this sentence "XX GAME お客様サポート係 横井でございます". 
I tried Google translate "横井" but it only shows "Yokoi" (the Japanese pronunciation). 
I also learnt about "でございます" is a polite form from this forum.
May I know what is the meaning of "横井"? Does it refer to the name of support personnel? 
And does "係" refer to "is" ?
Thanks.

Comment: @Wataru'Watson'Subridge: Sorry to interrupt, but I have a question to you., "Why didn't you write it to 'Your Answer'? " I'm just curious why many people avoid making "answer"s. Is it related to "to avoid getting down-votes"?  Your comment seems a perfect answer to this question. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't write answers in the comments section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

横井 is his/her family name.

～～係 means "the staff of　~~ division."

> “XX GAME お客様サポート係 横井でございます”

***This is Yokoi, a staff member of XX Games Customer Support.***

(Partially quoted from *Wataru 'Watson' Subridge*'s comment)